# threshold doesn't work when trying to convert PDF to .png

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have a PDF form that has a box like this:

[image]

I'm trying to run it through AWS Textract but it interprets the pipes in between the numbers. The pipes are actually like dark gray. So I hoped if I used Image Magick with a threshold I could get the number without the pipes but it's not working.

I tried this but any threshold amount doesn't help.

magick input.pdf -threshold 95% output.png

I'm trying to get something like this (which I did manually taking a screenshot and applying a threshold)

[image]

How can I achieve the above from the command line (or in Python)?

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust your threshold lower in Imagemagick.

```
convert img.png -threshold 60% x.png
```

[image]